# What are system requirements for the Linux server where are remote agent of Bamboo?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, bamboo, agent

What are system requirements for the Linux server where are **remote agent** of Bamboo?
I found the requirements only for the server where **Bamboo server** is: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-best-practice-system-requirements-388401170.html

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum the Remote agent needs JDK8 (or perhaps only JRE8), some memory - around 512MB at a guess, and the ability to be able to communicate to the Bamboo Server.

But if you want it to be able to do some useful work then you'll need to make other capabilities available to it, e.g. Ant, Maven, git, perhaps more memory... whatever is required for the work it is supposed to be doing.